# PostgreSQL heterogeneous insertion

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I have list like `["0", "s", "a"]` which is generated in process of evaluating , that list should be inserted in PostgreSQL with `postgresql-simple` where first column is `bigint`, but when I'm using

```
let vals = map evalVal field :: [String] 
execute conn query vals
```

I have error with wrong types conversion

```
Incompatible {errSQLType = "int4", errSQLTableOid = Just (Oid 25340),
```

How can I make library understand that first value is int?

Answer (score 1):

If you have three columns with types `Int`, `String`, `String`, then you can't represent a row of this schema with `[String]`, you have to use `(Int, String, String)`. If you change `vals` to this type, it should work.

Of course, this means your way of generating `vals` needs to change as well, since `map evalVal fields` only makes sense if the fields are all of the same type. But the details of this depend on what `evalVal` does.

Comment: Unfortunately, list size is changeable during computation. I'm using generic functions when it maybe 3, 4, 5, ... elements in list. I tried to convert list to tuple with TemplateHaskell, but we quasi-quotation can't be generated during execution, so again I need to know size beforehand

Comment: Is it always the first column that is an `Int`, and the rest are always `String`s?

Comment: Maybe I can generate for example all conversion function from 1 to 10 in TH, and then dispatch them in execution? I think I don't have more than 10 columns tables, yet. But don't know how

Comment: @FilipvanHoft: I wonder if you could use `(:.)` in that case, i.e. something like `[Int] :. [String]` for some `Int` and some `String` fields.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t::.